# looping variable in swift

Tags: swift, for-loop, uiimage

i want to change this variable become looping in swift:

```
var image1 = UIImage(named: "image1")
    var image2 = UIImage(named: "image2")
    var image3 = UIImage(named: "image3")
    var image4 = UIImage(named: "image4")
    var image5 = UIImage(named: "image5")
    var image6 = UIImage(named: "image6")
    var image7 = UIImage(named: "image7")

    images.append(image1!)
    images.append(image2!)
    images.append(image3!)
    images.append(image4!)
    images.append(image5!)
    images.append(image6!)
    images.append(image7!)
```

but my looping got error:

```
for var i = 1; i < 8; i++
    {
        var image(i) = UIImage(named: "image\(i)")
        images.append("image\(i)"!)
    }
```

how to get correct i inside var image and images.append name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to create a new variable for each image, try this:

```
for var i = 1; i < 8; i++
{
    images.append(UIImage(named: "image\(i)"))
}
```

This loop will create an array with 8 images without create the variables image1 to image8.

I hope that help you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
var images: [UIImage] = []
for var i = 1; i < 8; i++
{
    images.append(UIImage(named: "image\(i)"))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialize your your array first, and then you can do it with range
and also since you working with files it's a good idea to check their existence

```
var images:[UIImage]=[]
for i in 1...8{
        if let img=UIImage(named: "image\(i)"){
            images.append(img)
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure image1-7 actually exist in your project , (i.e. in Images.xcassets or as .pngs) otherwise `UIImage named` can't instantiate